# How super() implements in python programming

Tags: python

I am new to python programming, 
below is the example of parent,child classes,There are two direct super classes (i.e. bases) of C: A and B. A comes before B, so one would naturally think that the super class of C is A. However, A inherits its attribute a from T with value a=0: if super(C,c) was returning the superclass of C, then super(C,c).a would return 0 but its won't?

Could you please help me to understand why its returning 2.why not 0

```
>>> class T(object):
...     a = 0
>>> class A(T):
...     pass
>>> class B(T):
...     a = 2
>>> class C(A,B):
...     pass
>>> c = C()
>>>super(C,c).a
2
```

Thanks,
Hema

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with Python *method resolution order*, or MRO. The precise definition of  Python's MRO is here: [Python 2.3's MRO doc](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). Edit: [this explanation by Guido seems easier to read](http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html), and it includes an example exactly like yours.

If you call `__mro__` on a class, you'll see the order in which it looks up stuff. In this case:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.T'>, <type 'object'>)
```

So there you can see that it goes to B first, and only then to T. The reason is that it would otherwise be impossible to override attributes from T in B in this structure, and that's unlikely to be the desired behaviour.

Personally I just always avoid this diamond-style inheritance pattern, except of course for `object` which is the base class of every other class.